# Getting undefined data if i use onSelect in jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datepicker

I am using nodejs in back-end, For date-picker i am using jquery plugin.

My end date should not be lesser that start date so i used the following code

```
<div class="ipfield">
           <label class="plclabel" for="role_type">Start Date</label> 
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type="text" name="startdate" id="datepicker1" ng-model="userdatas.start_date"  class="txt_box" id="datepicker1" autocomplete="off">

            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="ipfield">
           <label class="plclabel" for="role_type">End Date</label> 
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type="text" id="datepicker2" name="enddate" ng-model="userdatas.end_date"  class="txt_box" id="datepicker2" autocomplete="off">

            </div>
          </div>

  $( function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        minDate: dateToday,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#datepicker2").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         dateFormat:'dd-M-yy',
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#datepicker1").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    }); 
});
```

Am getting undefined data in back-end

```
 app.post('/add_notification', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.body.msg['start_date'])
        console.log(req.body.msg['end_date'])
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Am sending the request through angularjs

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['countrySelect','ui.bootstrap','angularMoment','msl.uploads','angularFileUpload', 'ngMessages','ngTagsInput','ui-notification','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

app.controller('settingsCtrl', function($scope, $http,$filter,Notification) 

{
     $scope.add_notification = function(msg){
          console.log(msg) // here itself am not getting the value
            $http.post('/add_notification',{'msg':msg}).then(function(response)
                {
                $('#editModal').modal('toggle');
                if(response.data=='error')
                   {   
                  Notification.error('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><strong>Error !Please Try Again</strong>');   

                   }
                  else
                    {
                 Notification.success('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><strong>Your news/event is saved and will be visible to all users for the time period choosen.</strong>');    
                    }

                $scope.load_notification();    
                }); 
             }
})
```

If i didn't use onSelect am getting the data, but my end date should not be lesser that start date.

is any mistakes in my code?

Comment: how and where are you sending your request to the backend?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, am using angularjs, I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onselect` occurs after a user selects (highlights) some text in an input or text area ([documentation on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onselect.asp)).

`onchange` refers to modifying an input or select element ([documentation on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)).

You might have better luck using a different event trigger that fires after the change you’re interested in (updating input) is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I ll try to use onchange

Comment: Thank you so much I have used onClose . Working fine now